# What is the proper ember.js-way to react to a changing checkbox

Tags: checkbox, ember.js

I have a checkbox like this:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=property}}
```

When I click the checkbox the property is changed. Now I like to call a function to persist the property. But what is the best way to do this?

1. I could bind an observer to property, [but this is consindered bad.](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/observers/)
2. I could bind an action to input oder click.

   ```
   {{input ... input=(action "actionName") click=(action "actionName")}}
   ```

   This doesn't work because the property has still the old value when the action is called.
3. Extending the class Checkbox:

   ```
   import Checkbox from '@ember/component/checkbox';
   Checkbox.reopen({
       onChange: null,
       change() {
           this._super();
           if (this.onChange) this.onChange();
       }
   });
   ...
   {{input ... onChange=(action "actionName")}}
   ```

   But the function change [is not documented](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/Checkbox?show=inherited%2Cprotected%2Cprivate%2Cdeprecated), even though [the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/83263728b116fac6d4e8fcc798babf555a62ac2b/packages/%40ember/-internals/glimmer/lib/components/checkbox.ts)  indicates that it is feasable to override.
4. I could bind an action to didUpdate or didUpdateAttrs, but the action is called twice. In my case this wouldn't be a problem, because the property is part of a model, so I could call `model.get('hasDirtyAttributes')` in the action.
   **[Update]** In my test case the action was called twice but in my real code it is only called once, so this seems to be the best solution?**[/Update]**

So what is the proper ember.js-way to do this?

Comment: Do you find my answer helpful? If so please verify it. If you still didn't get a solution comment right below my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer one way binding with checkboxes. I use the native `input` like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{myValue}} onclick={{action (mut myValue) value="target.checked"}}>
```

Check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/43e44e724246c285a848609c84c1e5d0?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) to see it live in action. This is the easiest, non-library approach for 1-way bound checkboxes, which I would argue is the "ember-way" as of 2.x (although I do know people that still like and use the 2-way bound input which more requires observers in cases like what you described as far as I can tell).

In one of my projects, I use [ember-paper](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper) which uses a nicely displayed checkbox without `input` and I believe the correct aria-bindings for a11y. They leverage `click` to invoke `onChange`

```
click() {
    if (!this.get('disabled')) {
      invokeAction(this, 'onChange', !this.get('value'));
    }
    // Prevent bubbling, if specified. If undefined, the event will bubble.
    return this.get('bubbles');
}
```

such that you can use with the following api

```
{{#paper-checkbox value=value1 onChange=(action (mut value1))}}
    A checkbox: {{value1}}
{{/paper-checkbox}}
```

You can see the [example](https://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-paper/#/components/checkbox) and how the [template](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper/blob/master/addon/templates/components/paper-checkbox.hbs) and [component js](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper/blob/master/addon/components/paper-checkbox.js) are implemented for inspiration should you want a better looking checkbox than native

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5742fb40a3eb523f11f621f794020531) example.

I would suggest using `input` helper,

```
({input type="checkbox" click=(action "setProperty") checked=my_property}}
```

toggle the property inside the action

```
setProperty() {
  // toggle the property on click
  this.toggleProperty("my_property");
  console.log(this.get('my_property')); // returns true or false based on the checked value
  .. // do whatever stuff you want
}
```

If your at the most recent version of ember `3.9`, have a look at [this](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Checkbox)